# Scala: can't compile programme

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I installed scala on intellij IDE and used the following code to test whether it's working. My scala version is 2.12.4.

```
object learnScala {
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
 print("Hello")
 }
}
```

But I got the following error.
    Error:scalac: No 'scala-library*.jar' in Scala compiler classpath in Scala 
    SDK SBT: org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.4:jar

How to solve it?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with `java`.

Comment: Please make sure you've install scala SDK locally: https://scala-lang.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

You should have an overlay saying something like: "No SDK set for project. Please set up SDK" and a link inside the overlay.

If you don't have that go to File -> Project Structure -> Global Libraries

Comment: No it is something different, I have the same problem and configured Global Libraries.